# Windows Phone 8.1: Launch App for specific URL

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, launch

Is it possible to register an app to a specific URL (like http://dev.stack.com)?
If I click this URL as link in an email client, the app should start.

thanks

Comment: @Bugstand You can use deep linking url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the current SDK.

Comment: you can register for a custom protocol like your-app://any-parameter